# How do I change the default plain text mode to code mode like html?

Tags: vue.js, vim, frontend, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

[image: plain text mode]

How do I change the default plain text mode to code mode like html ? when using sublime I can simply change it the mode from plain text to html mode.

Comment: Likely it would be best to just install [vim-vue](https://github.com/posva/vim-vue) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `filetype` to `html` or whatever you want using:

```
:set filetype=html
```

**or**

```
set ft=html
```

Not entirely sure how vue works, but if the `.vue` files always has html content, you can set the ft to html automatically by adding the following `autocmd` in your `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufNewFile *.vue set ft=html
```